# How do I setup Cordova?

Tags: android, git, visual-studio, cordova

I am having some problems with getting started with my first Cordova app in Visual Studio.

When I create a new Cordova Project, I am presented with a page that says:

> We've detected issues with your system's environment configuration

And it lists 3 things that need to be installed:

- Android SDK The software is missing from your system. You may also have to configure it after installation. Instructions
- Apache Ant The software is missing from your system. You may also have to configure it after installation. Instructions
- Git CLI The software is missing from your system. You may also have to configure it after installation. Instructions

  1. I already have the Android SDK installed. So how can I let Visual Studio know where it is? A search for this on Google did not yield any results that were related.
  2. Searching for Git CLI did not yield any results. How do I install this?
  3. I haven't even tried installing Apache Ant yet because I can't get past the other two.

How can I install Git CLI and how do I let VS know where my Android SDK is located?

P.S. I am aware that each of those list items has an 'instructions' link, however, I am unable to access those pages, they say "Webpage is not accessible" in Chrome, Firefox and IE (and Spartan).

Answer (score 4):

I guess you have already installed Tools for Apache Cordova.

Once you did that and you can't install them with the tool, download them manually in their official websites. You can then add the path for these items in :

```
Tools > Options > Tools for Apache Cordova > Environment Variables
```

Here is a screen of mine :

[image]

I hope it helps

Comment: Before setting this configuration , we should define and set these variables name (ADT_HOME , ANT_HOME,GIT_HOME,JAVA_HOME) on windows From ControlPanel-->SystemSetting--> Environment Variables ,

Comment: Thanks @BipBip, that solved my problem. This should be the answer

Answer (score 0):

Not sure these are solutions, but something to check for:

If you're using VS2013, ensure you have update 4.  Visual Studio Tools for Cordova only relies runs on VS 2013 and 2015.

Of course, ensure you have the latest Tools for Cordova CTP 3.1 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42675)

In my system path, I have C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools. I have ANT_HOME as a system/environment variable set to C:\apache-ant-1.9.3. I have ADT_HOME as a system/environment variable set to C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk. I have GIT_HOME set to C:\Program Files (x86)\Git.

Answer (score 0):

**Setup your PATH environment variable on Windows**

[image]

From the Desktop, right-click My Computer and click Properties.
Click Advanced System Settings link in the left column.
In the System Properties window click the Environment Variables button.
Select the PATH variable from the System variables section.
Select the Edit button.
You need to add the path to your Android SDK platform-tools and tools directory. In my example I will use "C:\Development\android-sdk-windows" as the directory the SDK is installed in. Append the following text into the text box:
;C:\Development\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools;C:\Development\android-sdk-windows\tools

Save your edit. Close the Environment Variables dialog.
Additionally, you may need to include %JAVA_HOME%\bin to your PATH as well. To check to see if this is required, run a command prompt and type java. If the program can not be found add %JAVA_HOME%\bin to the PATH. You may need to specify the full path instead of using the %JAVA_HOME% environment variable.
Finally, you may need to include %ANT_HOME%\bin to your PATH as well. To check to see if this is required, run a command prompt and type ant. If the program can not be found add %ANT_HOME%\bin to the PATH. You may need to specify the full path instead of using the %ANT_HOME% environment variable.