# Android SDK Problems with Microsoft Studio 2013

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I am having problems with Android SDK being recognized by Microsoft Visual Studio 2013. I have put it on system environment variables and checked if it is right over and over again. However, at times when i open an apache cordova project, the front page tells me that it is not properly installed. I have tried uninstall and re-install it as well. I had to manually add in a path to the android SDK folder within the Microsoft Visual Studio settings although I had ADT_HOME configured under system variables.
Disregarding the the error on the front page, I can build and deploy the app on "Ripple - Nexus (Galaxy)" which makes me believe that the SDK is working. However, when i connect my phone and run on device or chose Android Simulator, it does not work. Here is what I get when I try run it on my phone.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: IOweYou, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(95,5): warning : The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.
1>  GeneratedJavascript=
1>  C:\Users\Sudin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\IOweYou\IOweYou>call "C:\Program Files\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat 
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.12.2 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\gl4alorm.pjd\packages\vs-mda
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-mda
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 0.1.75
1>  ------ Current globally installed version: 0.1.75
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
1>MDAVSCLI : [javac] warning : [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
1>MDAVSCLI : [javac] warning : [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
1>MDAVSCLI : [javac] warning : [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
2>------ Deploy started: Project: IOweYou, Configuration: Debug Android ------
2>Starting launch process C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe "C:\Users\Sudin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\emulator.js" --platform android --path "C:\Users\Sudin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\IOweYou\IOweYou\bld\Debug" --deployTarget "device" --language en-AU --configuration debug
2>  Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
2>  Calling plugman.prepare for platform "android"
2>  Preparing android project
2>  Processing configuration changes for plugins.
2>  Iterating over installed plugins: []
2>  Writing out cordova_plugins.js...
2>  Wrote out Android application name to "IOweYou"
2>  This app does not have launcher icons defined
2>  Wrote out Android package name to "io.cordova.IOweYou"
2>  Running command: cmd "/s /c ""C:\Users\Sudin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\IOweYou\IOweYou\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat" --nobuild --device --debug""
2>  Skipping build...
2>  Built the following apk(s):
2>      C:\Users\Sudin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\IOweYou\IOweYou\bld\Debug\platforms\android\ant-build\CordovaApp-debug.apk
2>C:\Users\Sudin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\IOweYou\IOweYou\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
2>throw e;
2>^
2>ERROR: Failed to launch application on device: ERROR: Failed to install apk to device: Error executing "adb devices": 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
2>operable program or batch file.
2>  Command finished with error code 1: cmd /s /c ""C:\Users\Sudin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\IOweYou\IOweYou\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat" --nobuild --device --debug"
2>  
2>C:\Users\Sudin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\IOweYou\IOweYou\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Furthermore, Is there a way to export the built package into an APK file so I can manually install it on my phone?

Comment: I think you have to submit your feedback in Microsoft Studio Team instead   SO.

Comment: Under their support page, they said that they checked stackoverflow constantly under the tag "Visual-Studio-Cordova". Hoping for the best! :) I should send them an email too tbh

Comment: From the error message, it says the adb tool cannot be found based on applied system envrionment setting. I think you can manually find the adb path in "platform-tools" under android sdk path. add the folder to the PATH system envrionment and try again.

Comment: About the visual studio installation, I don't think the installer didn't try to register the path. It might run into premission issue or blocked by anti-virus(something like that). Just try to install VS related things by "run as administrators“

Comment: Ohhh thank you soo much Alan. I went into the platform-tools and found out that abd was missing. I had another sdk folder in downloads from which I copied the abd.exe and pasted it into the platform-tools. The application loaded up on my phone and is working perfectly. However, after everything starts running, there is an error popup on visual studio saying could not run abd.exe. I am guessing it is cause i copied it from another version maybe. I might re-download and re-install the sdk to be safe.

Comment: Glad to know we made progress. :)

Comment: Thanks Alan, it is is working perfectly fine at the moment! :)

Comment: see this page : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520466/how-do-i-setup-cordova/29523150#29523150

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer here , is your android sdk path set correctly in VS ?

[How do I setup Cordova?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520466/how-do-i-setup-cordova/29523150#29523150)